# How to get all video elements with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, video, autoplay

I have a website that has multiple videos on a page. The number of videos varies by user. I would like all videos to autoplay when the user accesses the page. This is doable on desktop and iOS browsers. However, many Android browsers require a workaround for autoplay. See my code:

```
<?php 
  for ($i=0; $i < $videos.length; $i++) { 
?>

  <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source class="img-responsive center-block col-md-7" src="<?php echo ${'videos' . $i} ?>" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

<?php
  }
?>


<script>
 var video = document.querySelector('video');

 window.addEventListener('touchstart', function videoStart() {
   video.play();
   console.log('first touch');
   // remove from the window and call the function we are removing
   this.removeEventListener('touchstart', videoStart);
 });
</script>
```

I have tried both `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`. `querySelector('video')` obviously works for selecting the 1st video, but none of the following. `querySelectorAll('video')` does not select any videos.

Are there any alternatives to `querySelector` that would work?

Answer (score 6):

you can try

```
var videoList = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
```

this will return all the video tags from your page

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 video "autoplay" property should work with most browsers. You might wanna look at [Video Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Browser_compatibility), autoplay is on the second row.

To enable autoplay for all the videos on a page check out the code below:

```
<script>
  var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video'); // get all videos using "video" css selector
  /*Loop*/
 for(video of videos) { // use var video if "strict mode" is enabled
    video.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { // during the loading process
        video.autoplay = true;  // set autoplay proterty to true
      })
        video.load(); // now reload
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Most browsers put a lot of hoops to jump through at best to get them to respect autoplay.